# Hiding ads on my own YouTube videos on Apple TV

Tags: appletv, youtube

I'm going to set up an Apple TV at the office to show the company's own videos.

I thought about using YouTube, but I need to make 100% sure there are no ads are ever shown before nor after the video.

Is there a YouTube setting that controls whether ads are shown on my own videos? (For example, if I leave "Monetisation" disabled, am I 100% guaranteed that no ads will ever be shown?)

My alternative is Vimeo, where I pay a yearly fee, but I am guaranteed no ads.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable monetisation and you have no third-party content in your YouTube video, then no ads will be shown on the video.

You can check if Content ID has identified third-party content in your videos by checking your My Videos page as a link will be shown next to the video if this is the case.

Comment: They insert ads if they detect pop music in the video?

Comment: @forthrin Yes, this is an alternative option for the copyright holders instead of simply taking down the video entirely, and the money goes to them instead of you.

Comment: What if you already paid the copyright holder to use the music? Is there any way to tell YouTube this so the ads are removed?

Comment: @forthrin See [How Content ID works](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370) and [What is a Content ID claim?](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6013276)